# How to retrieve more than 2 properties in a path in gremlin.

Tags: gremlin

I wanted to get two properties as results but i got only one. what i did was using the given code in gremlin

```
  g.V().repeat(out()).until(has('title','school')).path().by('title').by('name')
```

how to get with both of them.

Answer (score 3):

The `by()` modulators are applied round-robin to the `Path` objects so, for the first item in the path you'll get "title", then the second item will get "name", then the third item, 'title'. If you want both "title" and "name" for each vertex in the path then you need to specify that in a single `by()`.

`by()` can take more than just a string (i.e. property key) as a value. It can also take a traversal and therefore you have many options to get what you want. Here's one way to do it:

```
g.V().repeat(out()).until(has('title','school')).
  path().by(values('name','title').fold())
```